# Consulta suma y resta del mismo campo sql

Tags: sql

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente como puedo sumar y restar en una sola consulta el mismo campo, en la misma tabla "entradas",  sería sumar un campo SUM(entradas.cantidad_ent) cuando el campo entradas.id_user = 0 y restar a esa suma cuando el campo entradas.id_user <> 0. Es decir obtengo dos sumas de un mismo campo cuando el campo id_user = 0 y cuando id_user <> 0  y luego esos totales los resto. Desde ya muchas gracias . Adjunto el codigo de consulta que deseo modificar

```
 $sql = "SELECT productos.id_producto as id_producto, productos.name, productos.marca, productos.proveedor, productos.stock_inicial, productos.fecha_ingreso, productos.nro_expediente,  productos.stock_actual, categorias.name, SUM(entradas.cantidad_ent)  FROM productos
   INNER JOIN categorias on  categorias.id_categoria = productos.id_categoria
   LEFT JOIN entradas on entradas.id_producto= productos.id_producto
   where productos.id_area='$id_area2'  and productos.precio_unidad != 0  group by id_producto ";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

// agrego captura de imagen de la estructura tabla

[image: deberia sumar 400 +1 y restar 8000, pero pueden existir mas valores en cantidad_ent con el campo id_user <> 0 por eso es la resta de las 2 sumas]

Comment: Suma condicional: `SUM(IF(entradas.id_user <> 0, entradas.cantidad_ent, 0))`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función agregada `SUM` para sumar los valores, junto a un `IF` y el signo menos (-) simular también la resta.

Si el `id_user` es diferente a 0, `cantidad_ent` será positivo, sino `cantidad_ent` será negativo, luego sumar todos esos valores con `SUM` (el query está simplificado para resaltar la solución):

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(entradas.id_user <> 0, entradas.cantidad_ent, -entradas.cantidad_ent))
FROM entradas
GROUP BY id_producto;
```

Comment: Perdón Vlady, creo que me exprese mal,  la respuesta esta casi cerca, pero la resta seria 8401 - 401, es decir suma todo y le resta la suma de los valores del campo entradas.cantidad_ent cuando id_user es = 0

Comment: Para qué sumarías todo si luego restarás los que no cumplen la condición, directamente en tu suma no tomes en cuenta esos valores.

Comment: También lo probé y me da 7599 en vez de 8000 :(

Comment: Sí, te entendí mal, pero hay otra duda, para qué sumarías todo si luego restarás las que no cumplen la condición, directamente suma las que sí la cumplen

Comment: Tengo que restarlos porque el código del producto es el mismo, los que poseen id_user =  0 son entradas por transferencia y no deben ser sumadas, los otros valores que tienen id_user <> 0 son los que debo obtener, y todos estan en la misma tabla. Si te fijas son tres tablas las que relaciono en la consulta obtengo id_producto , name ...de la tabla productos y name de la tabla categorias

Comment: Por eso, suma sólo los que cumplen la condición, en el `WHERE` de tu query pon la condición `id_user <> 0`, así la función `SUM` no los tomará en cuenta.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104940/discussion-between-julio-and-vlady).